# How to separate the report template and definitions in R.rsp?

Tags: r

[R.rsp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.rsp/index.html) is a powerful templating framework allowing to easily mix R and Latex code.

An rsp-file would look something like this:

```
<% myTemplate <- function(n, ...) { %>
The sum of $x=<%=hpaste(1:n, abbreviate="\\ldots")%>$ is <%=sum(1:n)%>.<%----%>
<% } %>

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
<% for (ii in c(3,5,10,100)) { %>
\item <% myTemplate(n=ii) %>
<% } %>

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Now, I would like to keep the function definitions and the actual report template in two separate files, so that different reports can share the same functions. It is easy to move the definition of `myTemplate()` into a new file, but due to the non-escaped Latex code  `source()`  cannot be used to import the contents of the file.

Would anybody have a suggestion or workaround to this problem?

Comment: Just wondering, but why have you chosen this package over sweave if you are producing latex output?

Comment: Looping over a mix of Latex and R code is not very easy in Sweave. In my view this functionality is better implemented in R.rsp.

Comment: Personally, I like using the `sink("out.rnw") / cat() / R / cat() / sink() / texi2dvi()` approach. Not sure what your usage case is though.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best solution for templating LaTeX reports in R is the combo `brew + tools::texi2dvi`.

The package `brew` seems to do the same that this R.rsp does. It replaces expressions into a text file by it's output from R.

Example:

```
\begin{document}
The result of $2 + 2$ is <%= 2+2 %>.
\end{document}
```

Similarly, it can uses functions created by the user:

```
crazy.function <- function(x) {
    (x + 2) * sqrt(x)
}
```

You just have to use it into your template:

```
\begin{document}
The result of my crazy function for 3 is <%= crazy.function(3) %>.
\end{document}
```

And have it defined before using the `brew` function:

```
# Defining the function
crazy.function <- function(x) {
    (x + 2) * sqrt(x)
}
# When we use the brew function, the template.brew
# is evaluated and a template.tex is created
brew("template.brew", "template.tex")
```

Then what we need to do is compile the `tex` file using the `tools::texi2dvi` function:

```
tools::texi2dvi("template.tex")
```

Therefore, what you need to do is define all the functions you will need. Use it into your templates. And then brew the templates into tex files.

**EDITED**

Just to complement the answer, if you like to keep the function definitions and the template in two different files, you just have to put the function definition into a file `function-definition.R` and source it before calling `brew` function. The template definition will be on `template.brew` file.

```
source("function-definition.R")
brew("template.brew","template.tex")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled upon this thread / answering in case someone finds this later / better later than never:

The `<%@include file="<pathname>"%>` preprocessing directive in RSP is designed for this, e.g. assume you have your RSP templates in a file 'templates.tex.rsp':

```
<% myTemplate <- function(n, ...) { %>
The sum of $x=<%=hpaste(1:n, abbreviate="\\ldots")%>$ is <%=sum(1:n)%>.<%----%>
<% } %>
```

You can then include it in your main RSP document as:

```
<%@include file="templates.tex.rsp"%>

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
<% for (ii in c(3,5,10,100)) { %>
\item <% myTemplate(n=ii) %>
<% } %>

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

The `<%include ...%>` directive is described in the main [R.rsp vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.rsp/).

/Henrik
(author of R.rsp)